# How to read consecutive .plt files and store them

Tags: python, file

I have 1000 files that I want to read with python. Before, I had 74 and I just read them one by one, but now there are too much to do so.

```
data_1 = np.genfromtxt('test4-1.000001.plt', delimiter=' ', skip_header=3)
data_2 = np.genfromtxt('test4-1.000002.plt', delimiter=' ', skip_header=3)         
data_3 = np.genfromtxt('test4-1.000003.plt', delimiter=' ', skip_header=3)         
data_4 = np.genfromtxt('test4-1.000004.plt', delimiter=' ', skip_header=3)         
data_5 = np.genfromtxt('test4-1.000005.plt', delimiter=' ', skip_header=3)         
data_6 = np.genfromtxt('test4-1.000006.plt', delimiter=' ', skip_header=3)         
data_7 = np.genfromtxt('test4-1.000007.plt', delimiter=' ', skip_header=3) 
.
.
.
.
.
data_73 = np.genfromtxt('test4-1.000073.plt', delimiter=' ', skip_header=3)
data_74 = np.genfromtxt('test4-1.000074.plt', delimiter=' ', skip_header=3)
```

I have tried to use a loop for, but it doesn't work. I tried to make i be a string, but still didn't work

```
for i in range(1:1000):
     data_'i' = np.genfromtxt('test4-1.00000'i'.plt', delimiter=' ',skip_header=3)
```

Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 4):

You kinda have the right idea but you made a few syntax mistakes, and it looks like you need to learn about lists.

What you should do is make a list of all your data. Lets call it `data`.

We define an empty like like this: `data = []`

To add to a list we use the append command like this:

```
data.append(np.genfromtxt('test4-1.000001.plt', delimiter=' ',skip_header=3))
```

The last thing is you were trying to concatenate your strings wrong. In python you concatenate strings with a `+` so this line: `'test4-1.00000'i'.plt'` should be `'test4-1.'+str(i).zfill(6)+'.plt'`. Note I had to turn it into a string first and I also used the `zfill` function to pad it with zeros.

Putting all this together we have the code

```
data = []
for i in range(1:1000):
    data.append(np.genfromtxt('test4-1.'+str(i).zfill(6)+'.plt', delimiter=' ',skip_header=3))
```

This will leave you with a list of data that you can call from using the syntax `data[23]` to get the 24th data set (list indexing starts at 0).

Hope this helped!

Comment: I wonder what's the solution if the file names are not so neat... Can I read in all the .plt files in a folder automatically?

Comment: Sure. You can search for files in a folder and filter by extension. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python

Answer (score 1):

```
data = []
for i in range(1, 1000):
     data.append(np.genfromtxt('test4-1.%06d.plt' % i, delimiter=' ',skip_header=3))
```

#### Edit

Loocid's answer explains how each part of this works.