# How to read in a lot of .plt files (whose titles are not neatly consecutive) with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-files

**(This question has been edited)**

I have **60 .plt files** whose titles are not quite neatly consecutive, so [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30746167/how-to-read-consecutive-plt-files-and-store-them) wouldn't work. What's the quickest way to automatically load them in order? I kinda hope I can put them all into a folder and write a function of the folder name.

[image: file title]

---

BTW, I really wanna automate this data loading process as there might be more .plt files in the future.

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/30746167/10077354

Comment: Yes, I did find it helpful. But some of the data (e.g date) are strings and numpy would read them as "nan". So I'm thinking maybe other packages can do the job?